# Using trim inside empty

Tags: php

How can I use PHP trim() inside empty()?

I tried:

```
empty(trim($myString));
```

which ended up saying:

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in......
```

I have read somewhere it's not possible, Still looking for some other way.

Answer (score 5):

If your version of PHP is prior to 5.5, this is not issue, but limitation of the language.

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
> result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
> empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

[empty();](https://www.php.net/empty)

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the trim before if you running PHP < 5.5:

```
$myString = trim($myString);

if (empty($myString)) {
  // Some code
}
```